# Run Django-Viewflow Update node?

Tags: python, django, django-viewflow

I'm using Django-viewflow to create a workflow programmatically.

This is my flow class.

```
class Workflow(Flow):

    start = (
        flow.StartFunction(function1)
        .Next(this.shipment_create)
    )

    shipment_create = (
        flow.Function(function2)
        .Next(this.request_quotes)
    )

    request_quotes = (
        flow.Handler(function3)
        .Next(this.move_package)
    )

    move_package = (
        flow.Function(function4)
        .Next(this.end)
    )

    end = flow.End()
```

What I do is, I start the flow programmatically, when a POST request is made onto an endpoint E1, I run

```
WorkFLow.start.run(**some_kwargs)
```

It starts correctly, and after the processing of the `start` is completed, then the response is returned back to the client.

Now, `shipment_create` is run when a POST request is made on endpoint E2, and I run it again programmatically via,

```
activation.flow_task.run(**some_kwargs)
```

It runs correctly and completes the flow up-to `move_package`.

**THE PROBLEM**

I update the details of `shipment`, via PUT request on endpoint E3, and I want to re-run the complete flow after node `shipment_create`. How can I do that?

1. How can I re-run the flow after a specific node?
2. Point(1) is a manual step, ie programmatically re-run the after nodes. Is there a way, I can include `shipment_update` node in Workflow class itself so that it automatically re-runs the after-nodes? How and where I would mention `update_shipment` node?

The problem I see in point(2) is, in one situation I am declaring `shipment_create` node after start (and the rest Handlers will process), and in another situation **I've to** mention `shipment_update` node after start (and the rest Handlers will process). How will the workflow class work according to the type of HTTP method?

**Updated**

How to return the response of Handler (ie `function4`)?

```
def function1():
    return 1


def function2():
    return 2


def function3():
    return 3


def function4():
    return 4
```

When `shipment_create` is run, the Handler is executed automatically. However, the response returned is that of `shipment_create` node, ie function2.

How to return the response of `function3(Handler)` or How to get the response of the last executed node before sending it back to the client?

Comment: The core problem that you don't follow BPMN practice. The goal of BPMN to explicitly describe a flow. You have no "Update details of shipment" on your diagram. You need to redesign your flow according to BPMN practice, with explicit update nodes that would show exactly when shipment update are allowed and what happens after the update.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the response. I'll alter my flow as per the BPMN standards.
However, how can I return the response of the `Handler(request_quotes)`, instead of the  `Function(shipment_create)`. I mean, when the flow is re-run from `shipment_create`, the response returned is that of the function associated with it. It does not return the response related to `request_quotes`, the handler.

Comment: Kindly see the updated question.

Comment: Starting a new thread for this question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51839068/django-viewflow-return-handler-response